# Mongodb java driver 3.0 query

Tags: java, mongodb

Hello i am working with mongodb java driver 3.0. i have a document like :

```
db.employee.find().pretty()

   "_id" : ObjectId("559e4ae4aed7561c94e565d5"),
   "empid" : 1,
   "name" : "abc",
   "dob" : "17/05/1990",
   "address" : [
           "559e4ae3aed7561c94e565d3",
           "559e4ae4aed7561c94e565d4"
   ]
```

I want to query on address fields and get all the addresses (in my case those values above) without specifying which value. My code is :

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable = mongoDatabase.getCollection("employee").find(
        new Document("address", 559e4ae3aed7561c94e565d3));
iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
    @Override
    public void apply(final Document document) 
        System.out.println(document);
    }
});
```

I don't want to specify the address manually. If I query on the address, I should get those two values. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why would you not be getting the whole document? That is what happens by default unless you specifically ask for something like "only matched fields" in projection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got the answer, we can query on the other known field for eg : empid and instead of returning whole document , only return the field which you require (in my case address).

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable = mongoDatabase.getCollection("employee").find(
            new Document("empid", 1));
    iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
        @Override
        public void apply(final Document document) {
            System.out.println(document.get("address").toString());
        }
    });
```